KOrganizer... Change weather temperature settings
I am using KOrganizer version 5.24.5 (23.08.5) to import my calendars from GMail.The app shows the weather and temperature but it is showing in C instead of F. I do not see any settings on the GMail side or in the app to change the temperature to F. Any ideas on how to make the change would be appreciated.
